# embed JavaScript in XML compliant JSP files (JSPX)

Tags: javascript, spring-roo, jspx

I am using Spring Roo for my project. Spring Roo is using JSPX for round-tripping.

How do I embed JavaScript in JSPX page, so it stays parsable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use CDATA and javascript comment.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    alert(1);
// ]]>
</script>
```

This will tell to XML parser that content inside `<script>` tag is ok.

Answer (score 3):

This is my create.jspx and you can find the way it works. I have used a file generated by Spring Roo. The modified part is in bold.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:field="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form/fields" xmlns:form="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" version="2.0">

**<head>**
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">          <!-- required for FF3 and Opera --><jsp:text> </jsp:text></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --><jsp:text> </jsp:text></script>
**</head>**
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
<jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<form:create id="fc_com_test_domain_Tag" modelAttribute="tag" path="/tags" render="${empty dependencies}" z="user-managed">
    <field:input field="id" id="c_com_test_domain_Tag_id" z="user-managed"/>
    <field:input field="tagName" id="c_com_test_domain_Tag_tagName" z="user-managed"/>
</form:create>
<form:dependency dependencies="${dependencies}" id="d_com_test_domain_Tag" render="${not empty dependencies}" z="user-managed"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, the job done by <jsp:text> (adding a space) just make this works!